# Почему может отключаться жесткий диск

Tags: windows, hdd, пк

Система установлена на SSD, есть еще HDD (#1) и HDD (#2).
Позавчера пылесосил компьютер, сегодня внезапно обнаружил, что отключился диск #1. Не было в биосе, не было в diskmgmt.msc, нигде не было.
Вскрыл компьютер, потыкал в SATA разъемы, сдул пыль еще, хотя ее там особо не было.
Все заработало
Где-то через полчаса пропал так же диск #2.
В чем может быть проблема?

Если поможет, комп пылесосил из-за того, что перестали работать два фронтальных USB 2.0 порта на корпусе системника. После того, как пропылесосил -- заработали. 
AIDA64 показывает следующее (но здесь нет HDD #2)
[image: Aida64 results]

Comment: Перетыкнуть в другие сата порты не пробовал? А если аидой начать стресстест - комп не вырубается?

Comment: @donRumata в другие не пробовал. А стресстест это какой именно? Хуже им не сделаю? Просто не очень во всем этом разбираюсь, а проблему как-то решать нужно

Comment: Погреть проц и память. Если у тебя после чистки плохо с охлаждением (мог зацепить или сдёрнуть) - комп вырубится быстро. Ну или в блок питания что попало. Стресстест плох, если его непрерывно гонять или если железо уже на исходе.

Comment: Чего-то Вы стронули. Может достать пыль из пылесоса и насыпать ее обратно? (шутка) Может 220В с корпуса пылесоса куда-то попало на материнку. Или статикой пробило. Пылесосили-то хоть выключенный комп или под напряжением?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Всегда, когда открываю комп (за исключением моментов, когда нужно проверить работу чего-либо), отключаю БП, вынимаю все кабели и вытаскиваю системник. Он уже день отработал после того, как пропылесосил, харды не отходили. Только вчера вот такое выдал. Сначала один пропал, потом другой, а первый вернулся. Думаю попробовать заменить SATA кабели. Стоит ли?

Comment: @donRumata прогнал где-то сек 40-70, ничего не произошло. Охлаждение работает, по крайней мере кулеры вращаются

Comment: [отключаю БП] А вот это зря. На выходе из БП стоит лошадиная емкость и через нее статика (в случае чего) замыкается сама на себя. Так что рекомендуется при профилактике выключать комп, но не отключать БП от материнки. Можно (и даже наверное нужно) вытащить из БП кабель 220 вольт, но от материнки БП лучше не отключать. Насчет SATA кабелей попробуйте, но по моим понятиям вряд-ли. Во первых теперь кабели заводские, это не PATA с хлипкими контактами "на протык". А во-вторых если бы кабель сбоил, то один, а не два сразу. Два сразу кабеля порвались как-то по теории вероятности не получается.

Comment: Ну а так-то теперь Вам по очереди все детали в компе заменять, пока не найдете что именно накрылось. Это нормальный метод диагностики для вычислительной техники. :-)

Comment: 40 секунд? Да ну. Минут 10-30 надо.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 сейчас вот вообще вроде все работают, ничего не понимаю. Не исключаю, что опять через час может один из дисков отключиться. Под отключением БП, если что, имею в виду кабель от него, который снаружи приходит (220 как раз) и просто кнопку, никаких шлейфов и прочего не трогаю. Неужели просто кнопка что-то может навредить? Зачем тогда она?

Comment: Кнопка на БП не повредит. Кнопка обычно отключает 220 на входе БП, но часто только одну фазу. А если все само починилось, то и не трогайте. Как говорится: "электроника это наука о контактах". :-)

Comment: @pepsicoca1 все еще ничего не отключилось. Неужели оно могло просто так заработать? Я просто так и не знаю, мне надо что-то менять, чтобы такого не повторилось или нет. А то еще ненароком что-нибудь сгорит. Спасибо за ответы!